How to Track User Login and Logout in Firestore with Flutter?
I am building a Flutter app where I need to track user logins and logouts and store this information in a Firestore collection. Specifically, I want to store the user's name, ID, and compound location whenever they log in or log out.
I have a Tablescreen where I want to display this information in a table format. However, I'm not sure how to properly track the login/logout events and update Firestore accordingly.
Here is my current implementation:
Tablescreen
This screen displays the login/logout data from Firestore:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Tablescreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenroute = 'Tablescreen';
  const Tablescreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Tablescreen> createState() => _TablescreenState();
}

class _TablescreenState extends State<Tablescreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _controller,
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              text: "Table",
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Select Table",
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Sort Table",
            ),
          ],
        ),
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            " Daily Reports",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Container(
          child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('signing').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
              } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                return Center(child: Text('No data available'));
              } else {
                final data = snapshot.data!.docs;
                return DataTable(
                  columns: <DataColumn>[
                    DataColumn(label: Text("FullName"), tooltip: "to display fullname of the name"),
                    DataColumn(label: Text("login"), tooltip: "to display Login of the name"),
                    DataColumn(label: Text("ID"), tooltip: "to display ID of the name"),
                    DataColumn(label: Text("compound"), tooltip: "to display Compound of the name"),
                    DataColumn(label: Text("logout"), tooltip: "to display Logout of the name"),
                  ],
                  rows: data.map<DataRow>((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    final Map<String, dynamic> userData = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

                    // Format timestamps
                    String formatTimestamp(Timestamp? timestamp) {
                      if (timestamp == null) return 'N/A';
                      return timestamp.toDate().toString();
                    }

                    return DataRow(
                      cells: <DataCell>[
                        DataCell(Text(userData['FullName'] ?? '')),
                        DataCell(Text(formatTimestamp(userData['login'] as Timestamp?))),
                        DataCell(Text(userData['ID'] ?? '')),
                        DataCell(Text(userData['compound'] ?? '')),
                        DataCell(Text(formatTimestamp(userData['logout'] as Timestamp?))),
                      ],
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Signin
This screen handles the user login and should also track login/logout events:
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Screens/Home_screen.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Screens/Registration_screen.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Screens/TableScreen.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Widgets/My_button.dart';

class Signin extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenroute = 'Signin';
  const Signin({super.key});

  @override
  State<Signin> createState() => _SigninState();
}

class _SigninState extends State<Signin> {
  var emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var compoundcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var FullNamecontroler = TextEditingController();
  var IDcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var logincontroller = TextEditingController();
  var logoutcontroller = TextEditingController();

  void _logout() async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      final userDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('signing').doc(user.uid);

      // Log logout time
      await userDocRef.update({
        'logout': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });

      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, Signin.screenroute, (route) => false);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  child: Image.asset('images/pro85guard.png'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 50),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: emailcontroller,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {},
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Enter Your Email',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 8),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: passwordcontroller,
                  obscureText: true,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {},
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Enter Your Password',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () async {
                    if (emailcontroller.text == "") {
                      AwesomeDialog(
                        context: context,
                        dialogType: DialogType.error,
                        animType: AnimType.rightSlide,
                        title: 'Error',
                        desc: 'يرجى كتابه البريد الالكترونى',
                      ).show();
                      return;
                    }
                    try {
                      await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: emailcontroller.text);
                      AwesomeDialog(
                        context: context,
                        dialogType: DialogType.success,
                        animType: AnimType.rightSlide,
                        title: 'Info',
                        desc: 'يرجى الذهاب الى بريدك الالكترونى وتغير كلمه السر',
                      ).show();
                    } catch (e) {
                      print(e);
                    }
                    AwesomeDialog(
                      context: context,
                      dialogType: DialogType.error,
                      animType: AnimType.rightSlide,
                      title: 'Error',
                      desc: 'يرجى التاكد من بريدك الالكترونى ر',
                    ).show();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 20),
                    child: const Text(
                      "Forgot Password?",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                Mybutton(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  title: 'SignIn',
                  onpressed: () async {
                    try {
                      final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: emailcontroller.text,
                        password: passwordcontroller.text,
                      );

                      if (credential.user!.emailVerified) {
                         
                          print('Full Name: ${FullNamecontroler.text}');
                          print('ID: ${IDcontroller.text}');
                          print('Compound: ${compoundcontroller.text}');
                          final userDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('signing').doc(credential.user!.uid);

                        // Log login time
                        await userDocRef.set({
                          'FullName': FullNamecontroler.text,
                          'ID': IDcontroller.text,
                          'compound': compoundcontroller.text,
                          'login': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                          'logout': null,
                        }, SetOptions(merge: true));

                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, Tablescreen.screenroute);
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, Homescreen.screenroute);
                      } else {
                        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.sendEmailVerification();
                        AwesomeDialog(
                          context: context,
                          dialogType: DialogType.error,
                          animType: AnimType.rightSlide,
                          title: 'Error',
                          desc: 'يرجى التحقق من البريد الالكترونى',
                        ).show();
                      }
                    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
                        print('No user found for that email.');
                      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
                        print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
                      }
                    }
                  },
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text("Don't have an account?"),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, Registrationscreen.screenroute);
                      },
                      child: Text('SignUp'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Problem
I want to:
Track and log the login time when the user successfully logs in.
Track and log the logout time and compoundlocation,ID,fullname when the user logs out.
Display this information in a table format on the Tablescreen.
Questions
How do I correctly log the login and logout times in Firestore?
How can I update the Firestore document with the logout time when the user logs out?
Is there a better approach to handle this tracking?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Track and log the logout time with compoundlocation,ID,fullname information of user

If you encounter problems, it's best to create a MCVE when posting a question. You posted more than 300 (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's way too much code for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read how to ask a question.
